# DataTables.Net Editor ajax data values in c# MVC controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi Im using jquery plugin Datatables.net editor in c#.

Im posting the following data in the ajax post (keyLastName).  How do I grab the data / keyLastName value in the MVC Controller so I can add this to the editor where clause? Any help would be much appreciated.

aspx code:

```
$('#Example').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "api/Testing"
                    ,type: "POST"
                    ,data: function ( d ) {
                        d.keyLastName = "testing123";
                    }
                },
                //displayLength: 100,   //rows per page
                sScrollX: "100%",
                sScrollXInner: "110%",
                scrollY: 600,
                scrollX: true,
                deferRender: true,
                dom: "Tfrtip",
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
```

Controller Code

```
public class TestingController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Testing")]
    [HttpGet]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Staff([FromBody] FormDataCollection formData)
    {

       //var queryVals = Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();
       //var ClientCode = formData.GetValues("LastName1"); //ata.ClientCode; //queryVals["ClientCode"];

        DtResponse response = new Editor(EG.WebApiApplication.Db, "Testing") //Global.asax.cs

            //This is hardcoded but need it to be from the posted keyLastName value
            .Where("LastName","Agnew2","=")

            .Model<TestingModel>()

            .Field(new Field("FirstName").Validator(Validation.NotEmpty()))
            .Field(new Field("LastName").Validator(Validation.NotEmpty()))


            .Process(formData)
            .Data();

        return Json(response);
 }
```

currently at the moment - I have hardcoded the value in the .where("LastName","Agnew2","=")  whereas I need this to come from the posted valued.

any help would be much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What is `d`? You can use `console.log(d)` inside your function to see what it contains. (You will have to open your developer console to view the log.)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string lastName = formData.Get("LastName");
```